# Does having form data save affect form error checking/validating

Tags: php, forms, error-handling

If your form has something like this in it

```
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>" />
```

to keep the information on a page refresh, does it affect form validating/error checking with things like

```
if($_POST['name'] == '') {
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `htmlspecialchars` converts certain html tags such as `&,<,>` into its corresponding entity codes `&amp,&lt,&gt`. These values will be in the text field. If you call `if($_POST['name'] == ""` in the next page after a `POST` operation, it will evaluate to false, since the `POST` field called `name` contains the aforementioned data, most probably along with other normal content which did not get converted by `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: Thanks I fixed it by doing this.
    `value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) : '' ?>"`